# Inhabilitar vuejs-logger en modo produccion

Tags: vue.js, configuración, logger

Me encuentro desarrollando el front de una aplicación con vue.js que utiliza webpack.
Estoy implementando vuejs-logger. 
Me interesa que en modo producción la salida no sea por consola sino a un fichero. ¿Alguien sabe como configurarlo
? Gracias de antemano

Comment: Agrega un enlace del repositorio o de la librería que estás usando